# How to explicitly cast a type in Go?

Tags: go, types, casting

I have a statically declared variable

`var fun *ast.FunDecl`

and an array named `decl` of tyle `ast.Decl` that holds items of different types `ast.GenDecl` and `*ast.FunDecl`.

Now, during runtime I would like to iterate over the array and asign the first occurring item of type `*ast.FunDecl` to my variable `fun`.

Within my array-iteration, where `d` is the current array element, I am using:

```
switch t := d.(type)
{
    case *ast.FunDecl:
    {
        fun = d // cannot use d (variable of type ast.Decl) as *ast.FuncDecl value in assignment
    }

    // more type cases ...
}
```

Also, trying to use the explicite cast

```
fun = *ast.FunDecl(d)
```

panics by saying:

> cannot convert d (variable of type ast.Decl) to ast.FuncDecl.

Beyond solving this particular situation, this brings me to the general question, how to deal with such a type-casting situation like that? How can I cast a variable to a specific type if I know that its type matches my cast?

Comment: 1. There are no type casts in Go. 2. `func = t` works as t is of type `*ast.FunDecl` inside _this_ `case`. 3. Type switches are covered in https://tour.golang.org/methods/16 . 4. Type assertions are not tape casts and are covered in https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to assign the type casted value t instead of d

```
switch t := d.(type){
    case *ast.FunDecl:
    {
        fun = t
    }
}
```

Comment: Pizza lord can you pls give me your bank account info, I would like to send you all the money I have! Seriously, I think I would have never come to this super-easy and super simple conclusion. It works like a charm! @Volker: See and learn on how to be helpful!

Comment: @marcwellman i am glad my answer helped you